# Django - must be unicode, not None

Tags: python, django, csv, unicode

im generating a csv file, and in some fields of my DB are empty, and when im creating the csv file this error shows "must be unicode, not None"

here's what im doing

```
def encode_notnull(field):
    if field:
        field.encode("utf-8")
    return field

clients = Usuario.objects.all()
    for client in clients:
        row = [
                client.casillero,
                client.pk,
                encode_notnull(client.tipo_rif),
                encode_notnull(client.rif),
                encode_notnull(client.razon_social),
                '',
                client.fecha_registro,
                encode_notnull(client.direccion_fiscal),
                client.codigo_telf_empresa,
                client.telf_empresa,
                client.codigo_fax_empresa,
                client.fax_empresa,
                client.correo_empresa,
                client.web,
                client.tipo_cedula,
                client.cedula,
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.user.last_name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.user.first_name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                client.fecha_nacimiento,
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.profesion).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.pais).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.estado).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.ciudad).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.urbanizacion).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                client.codigo_postal,
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.avenida).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                client.codigo_telefono,
                client.telefono,
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.tipo_inmueble).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.inmueble).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                client.codigo_celular,
                client.celular,
                client.codigo_fax,
                client.fax,
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.user.email).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.user.username).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.user.password).encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                encode_notnull(client.status),
                encode_notnull(client.tipo_cliente),
                client.autorizado,
                client.jet_info,
                encode_notnull(client.observaciones),
                encode_notnull(client.codigo_empresa),
                encode_notnull(client.cargo),
                encode_notnull(client.sexo),
                encode_notnull(client.departamento),
                client.celular,#decia cedularl ???
                '',
                '',
                '',
                encode_notnull(client.tomo),
                client.ano,
                client.representante_legal,
                encode_notnull(client.plan_inscripcion),
                client.numero_afiliado,
                encode_notnull(client.referido),
                ''
            ]

        writer.writerow(row)
```

what can i do? i've try checking if the value is none and returning "value = "none" " but it shows this error, "must be unicode not str"
traceback:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/descargar_clientes
>
> Django Version: 1.7.1 Python Version: 2.7.6 Installed Applications:
>   ('django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig', 
>   'django.contrib.auth',  'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions',  'django.contrib.messages', 
>   'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'adminplus',  'clients',  'currier')
>   Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/home/eloy/jet_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) File "/home/eloy/jet_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/eloy/jet_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py"
>   in _wrapped_view_func
>     52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/eloy/jet_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py"
>   in inner
>     204.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs) File "/home/eloy/jet/currier/admin.py" in descargar_clientes
>     126.                 encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.profesion).encode('ascii', 'ignore')) or "",
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/descargar_clientes Exception
>   Value: must be unicode, not None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your writer is expecting strings only, and you are clearly sending it a `None` which is the cause of the issue.

To override this, change

```
 client.celular #for example, assuming this is the line the error occurs
```

to

```
client.celular or ""
```

This way, if `client.celular` evaluates to `None`, the value `writerow` receives is `""` which is still a string. or `u""` if you want it to be unicode.

Comment: so, what i showed you was an example. looks like `client.profession` is `None`

Comment: i tried this encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.profesion).encode('ascii', 'ignore')) or "", and encode_notnull(normalize('NFKD', client.profesion or "").encode('ascii', 'ignore')), doenst work

Comment: buddy, doesnt work would not be very helpful to you and me.. Did you try to do `print client.profesion`, and print the output of the function call etc ???

Comment: umm, it prints "None"

Comment: exactly the issue right. which means the function should not be called if the value does not exist.